# How many HandlerMapping class is there in SpringMVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I want to know that how many numbers of HandlerMapping class in spring3.O, i am new in spring waiting for your response

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: See [the API docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.11.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerMapping.html), there's a list "All Known Implementing Classes".

Answer (score 1):

1)AbstractControllerUrlHandlerMapping 
2)AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping 
3)AbstractHandlerMapping 
4)AbstractMapBasedHandlerMapping 
5)AbstractUrlHandlerMapping 
6)BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping
7)ControllerBeanNameHandlerMapping 
8)ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping 
9)DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping 
10)HandlerMapping 
11)ParameterHandlerMapping 
 
12)RequestMappingHandlerMapping 
13)RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping 
14)SimpleUrlHandlerMapping