# What is the BEST HandlerMapping in spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

i am new to spring mvc development , i found a lot of HandlerMapping  in spring mvc as listed in this question

[How many HandlerMapping class is there in SpringMVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26815453/how-many-handlermapping-class-is-there-in-springmvc)

and i read that we can build custom ones to satisfy our needs  but for now i want know what is the best handler "best practice" mapping in spring mvc ?

Answer (score 0):

By default, spring uses `BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping` to map the request. This class searched in all controller classed to map the particular request with the method. I think, for beginner point of view  `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` is the best HandlerMapping.

> Note: By default this handlerMapping is not register. In order to use
>   this handlerMapping, you need to register it in your dispatcher servlet
>   file.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
       <property name="mappings">
         <value>
           /helloWorld.htm = myControllerName           
        </value>
       </property>
</bean>
<bean id="myControllerName" class="brajesh.com.HelloWorldController" />
```

Here, `/helloWorld.htm` is your action name.This will map your controller whose bean id name is `myControllerName`.

Comment: thx for the response but still this does not answer my question i am looking forward best mapping technique used in advanced projects

Comment: @Sam As you know each HandlerMapping having its own advantage. So Please let me know which type of requirement you have. According to your requirement I would suggest you , which one handlerMapping  is the best for your scenario.

Comment: i do not have any , just want to know the best to use like i said "best practice"

Answer (score 0):

Each handler mapping serves the special purpose so its totally up to the requirement.

So here is one nice article exclusively for handler mappings.

Please have a look on below URL for much clarity.

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-handler-mappings

Hope it helps..!!

Comment: thx , already read it , i was just hoping someone worked on a company real project and knows the best way to do it rather than what you want to do